# Why "class Meta" is necessary while creating a model form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import NewsSignUp

class NewsSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsSignUp
        fields = ['email', 'first_name']
here
```

This code works perfectly fine. But, when I remove **"class Meta:"** as below, it throws a ValueError saying "*ModelForm has no model class specified.*"

```
from django import forms
from .models import NewsSignUp

class NewsSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = NewsSignUp
    fields = ['email', 'first_name']
```

Can someone please give an explanation? :(

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344197/how-does-djangos-meta-class-work) explains better

Comment: @kt14 that's actually not the same: this is focused on generating forms from models, and the linked question is more about metadata within model definitions. Both, I have found, give complementary and largely nonoverlapping views of how `Meta` is used in Django.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are creating a *`ModelForm`* subclass. A model form **has** to have a model to work from, and the `Meta` object configures this.

Configuration like this is grouped into the `Meta` class to avoid name clashes; that way you can have a `model` *field* in your form without that interfering with the configuration. In other words, by using `class Meta:` you get a nested namespace used *just* to configure the `ModelForm` in relation to the model.

The namespace for the `ModelForm` class body itself then (outside `Meta`) is reserved for the form fields themselves, as well as form methods. You'd normally just let `ModelForm` generate those fields from your model, but you can, in principle, *add* fields to this. Another reason to put fields in the class is to completely replace any of the generated fields with your own version.

From the [*Model Forms* documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/):

> `ModelForm` is a regular `Form` which can automatically generate certain fields. The fields that are automatically generated depend on the content of the `Meta` class and on which fields have already been defined declaratively. Basically, `ModelForm` will only generate fields that are missing from the form, or in other words, fields that weren’t defined declaratively.
>
> Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, therefore any customizations made to `Meta` attributes such as `widgets`, `labels`, `help_texts`, or `error_messages` are ignored; these only apply to fields that are generated automatically.

Because `ModelForm` expects the configuration to be set under the `Meta` name, you can't just remove that and put `model` and `fields` in the `ModelForm` class itself; that's just the wrong place.