# What is exactly Meta in Django?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, metadata

I want know simply what is Meta class in Django and what they do.

```
from django.db import models

Class Author(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering=['last_name','first_name']
```

Comment: Meta classes are a python feature, not a django feature but django uses them. This will help: https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/

Comment: @DovRine: this is *not* a `metaclass`, since metaclasses are implemented through the inheritance mechanism (that would be `Author(models.Model, metaclass=...)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: You're right. I found this that helps me. Maybe you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344197/how-does-djangos-meta-class-work

Comment: it seems you haven't checked the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#meta-options). They're just a way to specify some standard options about how your model should behave. They are nothing to do with Python metaclasses (although it's an understandable confusion and one I had when I was first learning Python and Django).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Meta* is a word that originates from the ancient Greeks and it means "*meta is used to describe something that's self-reflective or self-referencing.*". Specific to Django it is a class in which you describe certain aspects of your model. For example how the records should be ordered by default, what the name of the database table for that model is, etc.

The documentation on [*meta options* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options) says:

> Model metadata is "anything that’s not a field", such as ordering options (`ordering`), database table name (`db_table`), or human-readable singular and plural names (`verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`). None are required, and adding class `Meta` to a model is completely optional.

The Django documentation contains an [exhaustive list of Django's model `Meta` options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/). For example for the [**`ordering`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering):

> The default ordering for the object, for use when obtaining lists of objects. (...)

Here the `ordering` specifies that if you query for `Author` objects, like `Author.objects.all()`, then Django will, if you do not specify any ordering, order the `Author`s by `last_name` first, and in case of a *tie*, order by `first_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a question about two different things:

1. **`Meta` inner class in Django models**:

   This is just a class container with some options (metadata) attached to the model. It defines such things as available permissions, associated database table name, whether the model is abstract or not, singular and plural versions of the name etc.

   Short explanation is here: [Django docs: Models: Meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options)

   List of available meta options is here: [Django docs: Model Meta options](https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2013/05/16/advanced-python-metaclasses.html)

Copied from here, consider liking:
[How does Django's Meta class work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344197/how-does-djangos-meta-class-work)

[Read this for further understanding](https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2013/05/16/advanced-python-metaclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

A Meta class in Django is a class that defines the behavior of other classes, such as models and forms. It is used to provide additional information about a class, such as its database table name, ordering, and other options. Meta classes are used to customize the behavior of Django models and forms.

For Django 5.0 you will find various class Meta options in the following link- [Django official Documentation of Class Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/options/)