# What is the use of class Meta in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have been using `django` and used `class Meta:` a lot of times, actually what is the use of it?

for example , In django `models`

```
class Accounts(models.Model):

   ---some code here--- 

   class Meta:
       ordering = [-1]
```

In django `forms`

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

   ---some code here--- 

   class Meta:
       fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is exactly Meta in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57241617/what-is-exactly-meta-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

`class Meta` is basically the inner class. In Django, the use of the `Meta` class is simply to provide metadata to the `ModelForm` or the `Model` class. It is different from the `metaclass` of a Class in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`class Meta` is used to change the behavior of the models such ordering, verbose_name etc. Though it is optional to be included in your models.

Answer (score 0):

`class meta`  is optional to use. but by using `class meta` your are just simply passing `metadata` to the `class model` or the `modelform`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Model Meta is basically the inner class of your model class. Model Meta is basically used to change the behavior of your model fields like changing order options, verbose_name, and a lot of other options. It’s completely optional to add a Meta class to your model.

Answer (score 0):

The Meta class is a special class used within Django models to specify additional configuration options that affect the behavior of the model, its database representation, and more. Some key functionalities of Meta within Django models are:

- Table Options
- Model Inheritance Options
- Field Options
- Other Options

You can enhance the functionality, usability, and organization of your Django models, tailoring them to your specific project requirements and ensuring efficient database interaction.

```
from django.db import models


class Ox(models.Model):
   horn_length = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
       ordering = ["horn_length"]
       verbose_name_plural = "oxen"
```

More options on [Model Meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/options/)