# How can I use composite primary keys in django?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, composite-primary-key

I want to use composite primary keys in django but I can't find a solution, I tried it in different ways, even trying to make an alter in the table but it won't let me, I want to use it based on this model

```py
class Contiene(models.Model):
    id_boleto = models.OneToOneField("Boleto", primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    boleto_cdg = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)  # Asegúrate de que este campo sea opcional
    num_orden = models.ForeignKey("OrdenCompra", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_total = models.IntegerField()

    def generate_random_code(self):
        numbers = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=12))  # Genera 12 números aleatorios
        letters = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=3))  # Genera 3 letras aleatorias
        return numbers + letters

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Si no se ha proporcionado un boleto_cdg, entonces genera uno automáticamente
        if not self.boleto_cdg:
            self.boleto_cdg = self.generate_random_code()
        
        # Llamar al método save de la superclase para guardar el objeto
        super(Contiene, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id_boleto}{self.num_orden}{self.cantidad_total}{self.boleto_cdg}"`
```

Where num_orden and id_boleto would become composite pk, please help!!!

I tried different composite key libraries but it gave errors when migrating

Comment: Django does not support composite keys, and they are not the greatest idea anyway. Why do you **need** a composite key? Why don't you simply let Django generate an auto-increment key for you?

Comment: @Selcuk There's nothing wrong with composite keys. The redundancy they produce can be of great use in some apps.

Comment: @TheImpaler Sure, maybe in some cases, and maybe in distributed systems. On the other hand, if you need a composite key it generally means that you are using columns that have some business meaning as your primary key, and this is not a good idea in most cases. Meaningful things can always change. Anyway, that's a separate discussion, but the thing is Django doesn't support them. From the example code this looks like an XY problem that can be worked around using a normal, single column PK.

Comment: Can you explain what the need for a composite PK here is? My Spanish is rusty (enough to be nonexistent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in my project and found this solution. By using Meta class, you can have a combination of pks. You can see the answer in the below cell. I hope this helps you.

```
 class Contiene(models.Model):
    id_boleto = models.OneToOneField("Boleto", primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    boleto_cdg = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)  # Asegúrate de que este campo sea opcional
    num_orden = models.ForeignKey("OrdenCompra", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_total = models.IntegerField()
    
     class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['id_boleto', 'num_orden'], name='combination_pks'
            )
        ]
```

You can also read more about the Meta class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992153/what-is-the-use-of-class-meta-in-django#:%7E:text=class%20Meta%20is%20basically%20the,of%20a%20Class%20in%20Python.&text=class%20Meta%20is%20used%20to,models%20such%20ordering%2C%20verbose_name%20etc.). I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is a separate unique constraint, not a composite primary key.